# Extract all links from a web page using python

Tags: python

Following Introduction to Computer Science track at Udacity, I'm trying to make a python script to extract links from page, below is the code I used:

I got the following error

> NameError: name 'page' is not defined

Here is the code:

```
def get_page(page):
    try:
        import urllib
        return urllib.urlopen(url).read()
    except:
        return ''

start_link = page.find('<a href=')
start_quote = page.find('"', start_link)
end_quote = page.find('"', start_quote + 1)
url = page[start_quote + 1:end_quote]

def get_next_target(page):
    start_link = page.find('<a href=')
    if start_link == -1:
        return (None, 0)
    start_quote = page.find('"', start_link)
    end_quote = page.find('"', start_quote + 1)
    url = page[start_quote + 1:end_quote]
    return (url, end_quote)

(url, end_pos) = get_next_target(page)

page = page[end_pos:]

def print_all_links(page):
    while True:
        (url, end_pos) = get_next_target(page)
        if url:
            print(url)
            page = page[:end_pos]
        else:
            break

print_all_links(get_page("http://xkcd.com/"))
```

Comment: Well, you use `page` before you define it right after the definition of `get_page`.

Comment: when I define page="content", I got a zero results

Comment: I would use `selenium` like so: `browser.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')`

Comment: Where are you expecting `page` to magically come from, exactly? Or the `url`, for that matter?

Comment: starting with line 8 you use the variable page, but where is it defined?

Comment: I know, but how to define it? when I define`page="content"` , I got a zero results

Comment: Just looking for some sample text to test your code on? You can right-click a web page and click "View page source" (or something like that depending on which browser you're using). That will give you some HTML text to use in place of `"content"`. Put this text inside of triple-quotes like `""" My HTML text goes here """` since this will allow you to specify a multi-line string which won't be bothered by internal quotes.

Answer (score 23):

`page` is undefined and that is the cause of error.

For web scraping like this, you can simply use `beautifulSoup`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer
import requests

url = "http://stackoverflow.com/"

page = requests.get(url)    
data = page.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)

for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    print(link.get('href'))
```

Answer (score 6):

You can find all instances of tags that have an attribute containing *http* in `htmlpage`. This can be achieved using `find_all` method from `BeautifulSoup` and passing `attrs={'href': re.compile("http")}`

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlpage, 'html.parser')
links = []
for link in soup.find_all(attrs={'href': re.compile("http")}):
    links.append(link.get('href'))

print(links)
```

Comment: Not my vote, but I removed the comment. I encountered the question in the Low-Quality Review queue. Voting is not possible there.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a bit late here, but here's one way to get the links off a given page:

```
from html.parser import HTMLParser
import urllib.request


class LinkScrape(HTMLParser):

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        if tag == 'a':
            for attr in attrs:
                if attr[0] == 'href':
                    link = attr[1]
                    if link.find('http') >= 0:
                        print('- ' + link)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    url = input('Enter URL > ')
    request_object = urllib.request.Request(url)
    page_object = urllib.request.urlopen(request_object)
    link_parser = LinkScrape()
    link_parser.feed(page_object.read().decode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: dear Mana - many thanks for this explanation - this is very helpful.