# Pull data from a website with multiple tabs

Tags: python, html

I'm trying to pull data from a website which is dynamically updated (every few hours or so), it is a website of a transport service and it has a few pages/tabs.
all i managed so far is to pull only the first page no matter what i try.
so i can't pull the data of the other tabs.
the code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer
import requests
import pandas as pd

# For establishing connection
proxies = {'http': 'http:...'}
url = 'http://yit.maya-tour.co.il/yit-pass/Drop_Report.aspx?client_code=2660&coordinator_code=2669'

page = requests.get(url, proxies=proxies)
data = page.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "lxml")

for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    print(link.get('href'))
    html = requests.get(url, proxies=proxies).text
    df_list = pd.read_html(html)
    df = df_list[1]
    df.to_csv('my data.csv')
```

i also tried doing it by parsing the html source code, but only got the first page as well, any ideas??

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you should extract the first page's hyperlinks and use it in your code!(if there is no hyperlinks, put other urls in the loop like below)

```
import pandas as pd

df_list = []
//call each page here. i assume you have page number at the end of main url
for p in range(1, n):
    url = 'http://yit.maya-tour.co.il/yit-pass/Drop_Report.aspx?client_code=2660&   coordinator_code=2669?pNumber=%d' %p
    df_list.append(pd.read_html(url)[0])

df = pd.concat(df_list)
print(df)
df.to_csv('my data.csv')
```

Comment: what does it mean to call each page?

Comment: you said you want to pull data from a website that has some pages. right? what i am saying is that, you just call one page, so you get the data of one page

Comment: i meant i have 1 url that has a dynamic table with several tabs (page numbers), and i would like to pull the data from all tabs and not for the first one alone.

Comment: right. call all the tabs address with their specific URL: url/tab1 , url/tab2, ... in a for loop.

Comment: If you can Add a picture of the site or say the URL, we can help you more

Comment: i added a picture of the table, since it's a dynamic table it currently doesn't have tabs, but usually it has just page number under the table

Comment: i cant read the data in the table, since its not in English but i think you can use 'BeautifulSoup' to extract the existing links, each time you want to read the data. see this link for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34610162/extract-all-links-from-a-web-page-using-python

Answer (score 0):

Every 15 seconds the webpage is calling the javasscript code below:

```
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
```

Open your browser dev tools and put a breakpoint in this function. After you understand the arguments that are submitted by the code, use [requests](https://pypi.org/project/requests/) (or other http client) to submit the form from your python code.

Comment: that's what i can't figure out how to do.